# First item of GridView should be a Gallery

Tags: android, gridview, android-studio, image-gallery

I have implemented a Grid View and a Gallery separately.Now I want to collaborate the two.That is,I want the first element of the GridView to be the gallery itself. Is there any way out?

Here is the code -

```
public class First_grid extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {
GridView grid;
Gallery myHorizontalListView;
MyAdapter myAdapter;



String[] name = {"Chocolate brownie", "Chicken burger", "Caramel cake", "Extra cheese pizza", "Chocolate ice-cream", "Chocolate drink"};
int[] imageId = {R.drawable.brownie, R.drawable.burger, R.drawable.caramel, R.drawable.cheese, R.drawable.choco, R.drawable.chocolate};

float width, height;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_grid);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    myHorizontalListView = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.horizontallistview);

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    myHorizontalListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    Custon_firstgrid adapter = new Custon_firstgrid(First_grid.this, imageId, name);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
          //something
        }

    });

}

public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {

}


@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    System.exit(1);
    super.onBackPressed();

}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    int[] itemsArray = {R.drawable.brownie, R.drawable.burger, R.drawable.caramel, R.drawable.cheese, R.drawable.choco
    };

    MyAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itemsArray.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemsArray[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemtext);
        image.setImageResource(itemsArray[position]);

        return rowView;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894043/dynamically-adding-grid-items-in-grid-view

Comment: This just creates a custom GridView. I want to know the process to have the first element different from the other elements.